# How to set Apache to accept override from .htaccess

Tags: php

I have tried to run php in .html file and failed despite trying all solution suggested here. Someone suggested it maybe because Apache is not setup to accept .htaccess overrides. Maybe that is the reason. Now the question is how do I setup Apache?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use .htaccess files, [the directive `AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) must be set for the directory into which you want to put .htaccess files. E.g.:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

This must be set in the core httpd.conf file of Apache. If you're on a shared host, you likely have no access to that (and that's correct, for security reasons).

Comment: How would I know if I am on a shared host?

Comment: Have you installed and configured Apache yourself? Then you own Apache. Or have you just signed up somewhere and uploaded some PHP files via FTP? Then you're on a shared host.

Comment: Uploaded files via ftp

Comment: Then contact your host to have them explain to you how to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: All I want to do was to run a simple php code inside .html file. I made the necessary changes to .htaaccess file. But I could not do it. I still can't do it.

Comment: Then contact your host to have them tell you whether it's possible to do this and how you'd do so in their particular environment.